# Android: Wifi Behavior in background

Tags: android

I have a question on Android about the behavior of Wifi.

I have an external device that communicates with the smartphone via wifi. I would like to know if I had to close the app in the background (or maybe lock the phone), the communications between smartphone and device are active or are interrupted or they continue to communicate?

Thank you

Comment: Most likely, your app can be killed and the communication can be stopped.
You can limited the number of allowed background processes in your phone's developer settings. Set the limit to 0 and test how your app behaves. This way you can test what happens when android kills your app when it's in background.

Comment: You can use a foreground service to keep your app going, and keep the CPU awake, but starting with Oreo, severe restrictions have been placed on using WiFi in Doze mode, and some devices won't even let you do it.